# CSS - Prevent child from having the same width

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML :

```
<div id="ohsnap">
  <div class="alert alert-red">First</div>
  <div class="alert alert-yellow">Second</div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS :

```
#ohsnap {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right:5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  z-index:99;
}

.alert {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #eed3d7;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.alert-red {
  color: white;
  background-color: #DA4453;
}
```

For some reason, the alerts (child div) takes all the same width. When the biggest div is removed, the width of all alerts divs are recalculated... I would like each div to take only the necessary space to show the text inside and not getting resized when others are delete.

What's the necessary CSS for that?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this i am not exactly sure what your asking?

Comment: Demo fiddle with buttons to toggle elements http://jsfiddle.net/ErR3z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with

```
.alert {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/MeNnv/)

Comment: This is often known as "shrink-wrapping", to size an element's width based on its content : http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/CSS-Shrink-Wrap

Comment: I had to wait some time after voting up your answer. Done :D

Answer (score 1):

Floating is an option, but it allows the alert boxes to get outside the edges of their container. Another option would be:

```
<div id="ohsnap">
  <!-- note BRs added below -->
  <div class="alert alert-red">First</div><br>
  <div class="alert alert-yellow">Second</div><br>
</div>
```

And add this to the CSS:

```
.alert { display: inline-block }
```

Comment: Nice! I prefer the Itai's pure css version, however ;)